# Google Calendar API - Insufficient permission

Tags: oauth, google-api, calendar, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I receive the following error when I try to add an event to my calendar.

```
 {
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
    "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
  } ],
  "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

I set the following permissions:

```
Google Calendar API .../auth/calendar   See, edit, share, and permanently delete all the calendars you can access using Google Calendar 
Google Calendar API .../auth/calendar.events    View and edit events on all your calendars  
Google Calendar API .../auth/calendar.events.owned  See, create, change, and delete events on Google calendars you own
```

What can I do wrong? What else should be set in my project?

Answer (score 1):

The Google calendar api [events.insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) method requires one of the following scopes in order to work.

[image]

This means when your application runs the authorization consent window must be displayed to the user where they will consent to your application having access to write to their calendar.

The following error message means that your application ran and the user consented to scopes where were not high enough to grant you access to use event.insert method.  You may have run your application and only consent the user to read scope.  This would not be enough for the application to run and then be able to insert an event

```
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
    "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
  } ],
  "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

Most of the time the issue is that the application ran once and requested a scope then the developer working on the application changed the scopes and neglected to force the application to request authorization of the user again.  Every time you change the scopes you need to remember to force the application to show the user the consent screen again so that they can consent to the scopes required of the application.

There should be a way of resetting the authorization in your application, however As you have not posted your code, or what language you are using its hard for me to tell you how to do that.

If you go to [security](https://myaccount.google.com/security) you can revoke access of your application directly in your google account, it will then force it to request authorization again.